# Do API gateways only have a single endpoint?

Tags: api, rest, microservices, api-gateway

I’m learning about micro services and API gateways. Some articles mention that api gateways only have one endpoint. Is that correct?

Let’s say my e-commerce page makes 2 calls, /products and /users to get products and user data, and they are in a Product service and User service respectively.

Does my client make calls to api.com/products and api.com/users separately? Or does it do api.com/exec?endpoint=users (or something like this)?

Answer (score 0):

From the context, it seems that the endpoint here is the domain - api.com. The specific url inside that domain, this is something for api gateway owners to decide on.

Typically there are two different approaches to api. In your example, there are two services and one way of exposing them to customers would be:

- products.api.yourcompany.com
- users.api.yourcompany.com

Clearly, each service would own its own endpoint (domain) and they can use any url format for specific operations; like /operationAbc or exec?operation=abc etc.

The second approach, and this is were api gateways shine, both services can be hidden behind single endpoint: api.yourcompany.com - and the api gateway decides how actual operation call looks like.